# How to get absolute path of file from another cwd with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, path

I'm running a Python script from the following directory:

```
/user/home/test_script.py
```

This script gets the name of a file in the following directory:

```
/user/folder1/folder2/folder3/this_file.py
```

So in `test_script.py` I end up with a variable that contains `this_file.py`. I need to get the absolute path of `this_file.py` to keep going in my script. In other words, I need `/user/folder1/folder2/folder3/this_file.py`

I've looked over a few forums and posts and have not had much luck. Using the `pathlib Path` module with the `resolve()` method seems to try and append my `cwd` to the beginning of `this_file.py`

What I have is:

```
# This is `test_script.py`

from pathlib import Path

# <function that parses a file and returns `this_file.py`>
foundFile = "./this_file.py"

# I try to make the path absolute
p = Path(foundFile).resolve()
```

And I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'user/home/this_file.py'
```

Edit:
I can get the path from a searching method and then pass the path in with the file name to the next method. However what I'm looking for is a way to get the path without having to search for the path seperately

Comment: How does your program know where `this_file.py` is if you don't specify a directory? And if you do specify a directory, what's the problem?

Comment: `resolve` doesn't raise that error. It simply constructs a file path; it doesn't care if the resulting path exists or not.

Comment: @Woodford at the moment, I have a workaround where there is a searching method to return that path. The reason I don't want to pass in a full path with `this_file.py` is because most of the time this will be in a completely different place. But you're right, there is no problem when a directory is specified

Comment: @chepner Interesting. Do you know what might be causing that error then?

Comment: Something in code you aren't showing us, I suspect.

Comment: Your code snippet is perfect. The snippet you hidden has some problem.